# How to download a database and integrate into the app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to download a database from a server and then use it in my app. My initial situation is that I've got a database in my assets folder and I am trying to download the whole database from a server when the user is clicking a button.

I think I have to use the onUpgrade method but I don't know how I can download the database and then use it or and load it into the assetfolder.

Comment: asset folder is only readable not writable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to brake the problem into smaller issues.

- Make sure that the server side is able to provide you with a web-service with which you'll do the actual download.
- It would be ideal if your server would zip your sqlite database in order for you to minimize traffic.
- After you have downloaded the db on your device, you'll have to unzip it, if you have taken this approach.
- When you get to the point of having the db downloaded and unzipped it's just a matter of connecting to a sqlite db and Android provides api in this regards.

Of-course, all of the above needs to be done in a multithreaded environment, you could also take into account using an Android service.

This is an example of downloading a file from a server, it should help you get an idea, it's not too generic, it works in my environment.

```
 private void handleSelectedItemDownload(final String downloadItem) {
    try {
        int bufferLength;
        long downloadedSize = 0;
        long downloadProgressBytes = 0;

        final byte[] buffer = new byte[12 * 163840];
        this.url = new URL(String.format(AppConstants.SERVICE_BASE_URL + AppConstants.MEDIA_IMAGE_REQUEST_URL_PATH + downloadItem));
        InputStream inputStream = this.getStream(downloadedSize);
        downloadedSize = this.chunkSize;

        if (downloadedSize > 0) {
            this.applicationFolder = downloadItem.equals("pictures") ? Utils.getThumbNailsFolder() : Utils.getApplicationFolder();
            final File mediaFolder = new File(this.applicationFolder);
            mediaFolder.mkdirs();

            final File file = new File(mediaFolder, String.format(File.separator + downloadItem + ".zip"));
            final FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            this.actionStatusProgressBar.setProgress(0);

            final Message downloadStartMessage = new Message();
            downloadStartMessage.what = ACTION_STARTED;
            this.actionMessageHandler.sendMessage(downloadStartMessage);

            int progressBarMax = (int) (this.totalDownloadSize / 1024);
            this.actionStatusProgressBar.setMax(progressBarMax);


            while (chunkSize != 0) {
                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadProgressBytes += bufferLength;

                    final Message currentProgressMessage = new Message();
                    currentProgressMessage.arg1 = (int) (downloadProgressBytes / 1024);
                    currentProgressMessage.what = ACTION_PROGRESS_VALUE;
                    this.actionMessageHandler.sendMessage(currentProgressMessage);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                this.urlConnection.disconnect();

                inputStream = this.getStream(downloadedSize);
                downloadedSize += chunkSize;
            }
            fileOutput.close();
        }

        this.urlConnection.disconnect();
        this.totalDownloadSize = 0;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("DOWNLOAD_ERROR", e.getMessage() + e.toString());
        this.errorEncountered = true;
        this.actionType = IDataActionListener.ACTION_TYPE.ACTION_FAILED;
        this.actionMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(ERROR_ENCOUNTERED);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("DOWNLOAD_ERROR", e.getMessage() + e.toString());
        this.errorEncountered = true;
        this.actionType = IDataActionListener.ACTION_TYPE.ACTION_FAILED;
        this.actionMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(ERROR_ENCOUNTERED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DOWNLOAD_ERROR", e.getMessage() + e.toString());
        this.errorEncountered = true;
        this.actionType = IDataActionListener.ACTION_TYPE.ACTION_FAILED;
        this.actionMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(ERROR_ENCOUNTERED);
    }
}  

private InputStream getStream(final long downloadedSize) throws IOException {
    this.urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();

    this.urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    this.urlConnection.addRequestProperty("DOWNLOADED_SIZE", String.valueOf(downloadedSize));

    final InputStream inputStream = this.urlConnection.getInputStream();
    this.chunkSize = this.urlConnection.getContentLength();
    if (!Utils.stringIsNullOrEmpty(this.urlConnection.getHeaderField("TOTAL_SIZE"))) {
        if (this.totalDownloadSize == 0) {
            this.totalDownloadSize = Long.parseLong(this.urlConnection.getHeaderField("TOTAL_SIZE"));
        }
    }
    return inputStream;
}
```

Afterwards, when you have downloaded your db file, you can just create a SQLiteDatabase object:

```
 final File dbFile = new File(filePath);

    if (dbFile.exists()) {
        this.localDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(filePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        this.localDatabase.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    }
```

I still stick to the opinion that you should also give zipping a thought, you reduce a LOT the traffic and the time spent over network.

Comment: Yeah ive got an server and everthing. I dont need to zip my database because its about 2 MB size.
Can you give me an tutorial or something. Please

Comment: I've added some pieces of code, have a look over, it should help you get an idea, otherwise I could probably pm you with some further explanations.

Comment: is it possible to download the whole database in an easier way?

Comment: well, if you're interested in simply downloading and not bother with too much details you could hook up to android's download manager, see this example: http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

Comment: but please can you post the import statements?

Comment: which import statements?